# find the date range of groupped data in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with 15-minutes observations for different stations for 20 years. I want to know the range time that each station has data.

| station_id | start_time | end_time | observation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2000-01-02 01:00:00 | 2000-01-02 01:15:00 | 50 |
| 2 | 2000-01-02 01:15:00 | 2000-01-02 01:30:00 | 15 |
| 2 | 2000-02-02 01:30:00 | 2000-01-02 01:45:00 | 3 |
| 3 | 2000-01-02 05:00:00 | 2000-01-02 05:15:00 | 10 |
| 3 | 2000-01-02 05:15:00 | 2000-01-02 05:30:00 | 2 |
| 3 | 2000-02-03 01:00:00 | 2000-01-02 01:15:00 | 15 |
| 3 | 2000-02-04 01:00:00 | 2000-01-02 01:15:00 | 20 |

an example of I want to have

```
|station_id |      start        |      end          |     years    |days
|    2      |2000-01-02 01:00:00|2000-01-02 01:45:00|       1     | 1
|    3      |2000-01-02 05:00:00|2000-01-02 01:15:00|       1     | 1
```

Comment: Is `observation` the desired column?

Comment: What would be the expected output here?

Comment: Could you specify the logic to this?

Comment: I want to know how many years, and days I do have data for each station and later, I need to sum the counts in observations.

Comment: @GeoBeez Then how is the first observation `50`?

Comment: This is a traffic monitoring system. I do have 20 years of data for 5000 stations. every 15minutes. The observations are the traffic counts. I want to find how many stations have full data and how their traffic has changed over time.

Comment: @GeoBeez Are the data all sorted?

Comment: they are sorted based on time but the stations are in between too.

Comment: @GeoBeez Gotcha, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `groupby`, `diff`, `abs`, `agg` and `assign`:

```
df[['start_time', 'end_time']] = df[['start_time', 'end_time']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
x = df.groupby('station_id').agg({'start_time': 'first', 'end_time': 'last'})
temp = x.diff(axis=1).abs()['end_time']
x = x.assign(years=temp.dt.days // 365, days=temp.dt.days % 365).reset_index()
print(x)
```